# Angular 2 - MEAN MongoDB NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, components

I'm using this GitHub example (https://github.com/bradtraversy/mean_mytasklist) and it works fine so far. I see the tasks of my MongoDB, can add, delete tasks.

Then I was trying to add a new component "header"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'headers',
  templateUrl: 'header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

I added this component in my app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TasksComponent } from './components/tasks/tasks.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, TasksComponent, HeaderComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my app.component.html I am using this selector.

```
<div class="container">
    <headers></headers>
    <h1>MyTaskList</h1>
    <hr>
    <tasks></tasks>
</div>
```

After refreshing my browser I'll get this error message:

zone.js:420 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'headers' is not a known element:
1. If 'headers' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'headers' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    [ERROR ->]

```
<headers></headers>
<h1>MyTaskList</h1>
<hr>
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!!!

"): AppComponent@1:4 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ;

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Angular 2 you are using  & You are not using webpack for build ?

The solution is mentioned in the error console itself.
You need to add

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
```

So your app.module.ts should look something like this,

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, TasksComponent, HeaderComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still get the same error. 

CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA allows 
--> any non-Angular elements with a - in their name and 
--> any properties on elements with a - in their name which is the common rule for custom elements (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA-let.html).

I only use "header" as selector.

What surprises me is, that the task-component (see GitHub-example) is working.

Comment: I suppose you were on the right path. It seems like I'm using an old version of Angular. There was an bugreport which describes exactly my problem (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11426). Where can I check my version? How can I update my Angular? THX!!!

Comment: Try changing your component selector to custom-header if it works for you .!! Check your package.json for angular version.